# Banker's Rounding in Dart

Tags: dart, double, precision

Can anyone help with a Banker's rounding implementation in Dart please

So i round 3 d.p. to the nearest 2 d.p. number EXCEPT when the number is halfway between it goes to the **nearest even number**

eg

```
print(1.011.toStringAsFixed(2)); // rounds down to 1.01
print(1.019.toStringAsFixed(2)); // rounds up to 1.02
print(1.015.toStringAsFixed(2)); // rounds down to 1.01 but i want up to 1.02
print(1.025.toStringAsFixed(2)); // rounds down to 1.02
```

Comment: wow... if the developers of this language claim this is a feature, I'm very very curious why....

Comment: may be worth checking this out markusrambarkus http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1UCRko23/

Answer (score 3):

I have same requirement, so i build one.

banker_rounding.dart

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

Decimal _getDecimalOfNumber(Decimal number, int fractionDigits) => number - (number.floor());

Decimal _pow10(int powNum) => Decimal.parse(pow(10, powNum).toString());

Decimal _carryLatest(Decimal number) {
  int decimalLength = number.toString().length - 2;
  Decimal offset = _pow10(-decimalLength);
  return number + offset;
}

Decimal bankerRound(Decimal value, int fractionDigits) {
  // integer of number
  Decimal integerOfNumber = value.floor();
  // decimal of number
  Decimal decimalOfNumber = _getDecimalOfNumber(value, fractionDigits);
  // remain flag
  int remainFlag = (decimalOfNumber * _pow10(fractionDigits + 1) % Decimal.fromInt(10)).toInt();
  Decimal finalMultiple = _pow10(fractionDigits);
  Decimal finalDecimalOfNumber = ((decimalOfNumber * finalMultiple).floor() / finalMultiple);
  if (remainFlag <= 4) {
    // do nothing
  } else if (remainFlag >= 6) {
    // carry
    finalDecimalOfNumber = _carryLatest(finalDecimalOfNumber);
  } else {
    // check bottom has number
    bool hasBottom = _getDecimalOfNumber(decimalOfNumber * _pow10(fractionDigits + 1), fractionDigits) != Decimal.zero;
    if (hasBottom) {
      // carry
      finalDecimalOfNumber = _carryLatest(finalDecimalOfNumber);
    } else {
      // check pre remain flag
      int preLastNumber = (decimalOfNumber * _pow10(fractionDigits) % Decimal.fromInt(10)).toInt();
      if (preLastNumber.isOdd) {
        // carry
        finalDecimalOfNumber = _carryLatest(finalDecimalOfNumber);
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }
    }
  }
  return integerOfNumber + finalDecimalOfNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested banker round to a whole numbers algorithm.
For Decimal (100% accurate):

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

var _halfDec = Decimal.parse('0.5');
Decimal bankerRoundDecimal(Decimal value) {
  var rounded = value.round();
  if(rounded - value == _halfDec)
    if(value.ceil().toInt() % 2 != 0)
      rounded = value.floor();

  return rounded;
}
```

And for double:

```dart
double bankerRound(double value) {
  var rounded = value.roundToDouble();
  if(((rounded - value) * 100).round() == 50)
    if(value.ceil() % 2 != 0)
      rounded = value.floorToDouble();

  return rounded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I follow this [docuemnt](https://cplusplus.com/articles/1UCRko23/) and write another for Dart.

[Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1300963a6be50844e332c059ef27c2c1)

```dart
double roundHalfEven(double value, {double epsilon = 0.0000001}) {
  if (value < 0.0) return -roundHalfEven(-value, epsilon: epsilon);
  double ipart = value.toInt().toDouble();

  // If 'value' is exctly halfway between two integers
  if ((value - (ipart + 0.5)).abs() < epsilon) {
    // If 'ipart' is even then return 'ipart'
    if (ipart % 2.0 < epsilon) {
      return ipart;
    }

    // Else return the nearest even integer
    return (ipart + 0.5).ceilToDouble();
  }

  // Otherwise use the usual round to closest
  // (Either symmetric half-up or half-down will do0
  return value.roundToDouble();
}
```

Test

```kotlin
import java.math.*

fun main() {
    println(BigDecimal(4.5).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // 4
    println(BigDecimal(3.5).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // 4
    println(BigDecimal(4.500001).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // 5
    println(BigDecimal(3.500001).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // 4
    println("--------")
    println(BigDecimal(-4.5).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // -4
    println(BigDecimal(-3.5).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // -4
    println(BigDecimal(-4.500001).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // -5
    println(BigDecimal(-3.500001).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)) // -4
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  print(roundHalfEven(4.5)); // 4
  print(roundHalfEven(3.5)); // 4
  print(roundHalfEven(4.500001)); // 5
  print(roundHalfEven(3.500001)); // 4
  print('-------');
  print(roundHalfEven(-4.5)); // -4
  print(roundHalfEven(-3.5)); // -4
  print(roundHalfEven(-4.500001)); // -5
  print(roundHalfEven(-3.500001)); // -4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform financial rounding, you can utilize this code, which is based on the decimal package.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

Decimal roundHalfEven(Decimal originalValue, {int targetDecimalPlaces = 0}) {
  final int currentDecimalPlaces = originalValue.scale;

  if (targetDecimalPlaces >= currentDecimalPlaces) {
    return originalValue;
  }

  final int decimalPlacesToRemove = currentDecimalPlaces - targetDecimalPlaces;

  final Decimal scaleFactor =
      toDecimal(math.pow(10, currentDecimalPlaces).toDouble());
  final scaledValue = (originalValue * scaleFactor).toBigInt();

  final BigInt dividend = scaledValue;
  final BigInt divisor = BigInt.from(10).pow(decimalPlacesToRemove);

  final quotient = dividend ~/ divisor;
  final remainder = dividend.remainder(divisor).abs();
  final isQuotientPositive = dividend.sign == divisor.sign;

  final Decimal newScaleFactor =
      toDecimal(math.pow(10, targetDecimalPlaces).toDouble());

  if (remainder != BigInt.zero) {
    if (shouldIncrement(
      divisor: divisor,
      quotient: quotient,
      remainder: remainder,
    )) {
      final adjustedQuotient =
          quotient + (isQuotientPositive ? BigInt.one : -BigInt.one);

      return divide(
        dividend: adjustedQuotient.toDecimal(),
        divisor: newScaleFactor,
      );
    }
  }
  return divide(dividend: quotient.toDecimal(), divisor: newScaleFactor);
}

Decimal toDecimal(dynamic value) => Decimal.parse(value.toString());

bool shouldIncrement({
  required BigInt divisor,
  required BigInt quotient,
  required BigInt remainder,
}) {
  final remainderComparisonToHalfDivisor =
      (remainder * BigInt.from(2)).compareTo(divisor);

  if (remainderComparisonToHalfDivisor < 0) {
    return false;
  } else if (remainderComparisonToHalfDivisor > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return quotient.isOdd;
  }
}

Decimal divide({required Decimal dividend, required Decimal divisor}) {
  final valorRacional = dividend / divisor;

  return valorRacional.toDecimal(scaleOnInfinitePrecision: 15);
}
```